# Streaming webcam to rtmp with

Tags: node.js, browser, streaming, webrtc, rtmp

What's the best way to do so If I don't want to use flash?

I heard about WebRTC but is it viable to take input from `getUserMedia`
 and stream it to a media server which will then move that data to an rtmp stream?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the media server you use. For example, Wowza has been adding WebRTC support recently: https://www.wowza.com/products/capabilities/webrtc-streaming-software

I don't know of any way to get WebRTC input to a media server that doesn't support it.